# Blazor Property for CssClass so that intelisense will work

Tags: css, blazor

In the old WebForms days if you specified [CssClassProperty] for the property like CssClass of a component.

```
[CssClassProperty] public string CssClass { get; set; } = string.Empty;
```

Then used that component intelisense would kick in when you used that comp and you were specifying the value of that property.  What's the equivalent for Blazor components.

```
[Property] public string CssClass { get; set; } = string.Empty;
```

I've done google searches and searched through stackoverflow but there doesn't seem to be any reference to this.